# psycopg2 - use the same database instance connection to read data from multiple databases

Tags: python, amazon-rds, psycopg2, psql

I have one database instance that has multiple databases. The database instance is a Postgres AWS RDS instance.
My goal is to select data from multiple databases using the same DB connection.

This is an example of my database connection handler:

```py
class BMR_Connection:
    """connect to BMRS db to get past messeges"""

    def __init__(self):
        # connect to the database
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
            dbname=config.dbname1,
            user=config.user,
            password=config.password,
            host=config.host,
        )
        self.connection.autocommit = True
        self.cursor = self.connection.cursor()
  
            
    def get_data(self):
        sql_command = """
        SELECT *
        from public.datatable1
            """  
        self.cursor.execute(sql_command)
        rows = self.cursor.fetchall()
```

And I have three similar database connection handler classes

```
BMS_Connection
BMT_Connection
BMU_Connection
```

that are connecting to the same database instance `config.host`, using the same username `config.user` and password `config.password` , But picking data from different databases of that instance like

```
config.dbname2
config.dbname3
config.dbname4
```

Is there a way I can establish a connection to the database instance and then specify the database I want to read data from in sql queries?
By doing that, I would only specify host name during connection

```py
        self.connection = psycopg2.connect(
            user=config.user,
            password=config.password,
            host=config.host,
        )
```

And then specify the database name in SQL queries

```py
        sql_command = f"""
            FROM DATABASE {dbname1}
            SELECT *
            from public.datatable1
        """
```

Comment: have you tried defining multiple `connections`? I know its still but should work in my opinion

Comment: That is what I'm using. I'm looking for something better

Comment: You can't change databases in PostgreSQL without making a new connection.

Comment: Technically you could use an extension like [dblink](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/contrib-dblink-function.html) or [postgres_fdw](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/postgres-fdw.html) to SELECT data from multiple databases at once, but I don't think this is what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: My goal is to select data from multiple databases using the same DB connection.